# Steps needed to install a PHP application (Mantis) on Windows Home Server - How please?

Tags: php, mantis, bug-tracker

I'm using Windows Home Server and have already managed to install SVN on it to allow me to use Tortoise SVN on client PC's sharing a repository on the server via SVN's service and port.

I'd now like to install a bug tracker hosted on this server. I'm not fussy about which one but I saw Mantis - which is a PHP application and looks ok for my purpose. This is where I get weak on such stuff - what steps do I need to do to install and configure PHP (and presumably MySql to get mantis working? It is an http application.

As an alternate answer, I'd be happy to use another - more easily installed - bug tracker that has a server service and a port of its own.

I'll appreciate any comments.

Comment: This should probably go on Superuser.com, as the question is not directly programming related.

Comment: @Galen: What a fascinating programming concept. I'd never heard of WAMP - thanks, off to try.

Answer (score 0):

We use WampServer (at  http://www.wampserver.com/en/) with Mantis. I prefer trac, but it's a pain getting Python running on WampServer. For the most part it's a case of running the WampServer installer then copying Mantis to your document root and following the instructions from there, but it has the flexibility of having the (albeit slightly modified) configs for Apache, MySQL and PHP to fully customise them. If you install WampServer on the same machine as your SVN server, you can also hook the two up together (we have post-commit scripts running to automatically mark bugs as closed after committing).

Another bonus of using WampServer is you can download alternative Apache, MySQL and PHP versions as separate installs - I had to do this when PHP 5.3.0 needed upgrading as it had a few bugs.